# how do I play audio on a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

My `javascript` has a `prototype` `function` that intersects `user inputs` and a `song database`, returning `Song.name`. This `function` works fine by itself.

Given my `HTML` `<audio id="songname" src="audio/song.wav" preload="auto"></audio>`, now I am trying to actually PLAY the `audio` file on a page.

for this `event` `<button id="mybutton" onclick="play_song();">play</button>` I have tried:

```
   function play_song() {
    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var element = document.getElementById('id');
    element.play();
}
```

but I'm getting `null`.

how do I make this `function` work?

Comment: So if your prototype lyricsIntersect works, and your element is valid, doesn't `element.play()` work?

Comment: no, it doesn't work! if i try `var x = document.getElementById("songx") and x.play( )`, I get playback. so yes, element is valid. something wrong with the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function play_song() {
    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.play();
}
```

Comment: tried...`console.log` returns "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null`"

Comment: What is the song's ID (in html)? What does `Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input)` return?

Comment: `html`: `<audio id="Hot Bit Soup" src="audio/Hot Bit Soup.wav" preload="auto"></audio>`. and `prototype` returns "Hot Bit Soup"

Comment: You can't have any spaces for html IDs. Can you try changing the ID to `hot_bit_soup`?

Comment: tried. changed it to Hot_Bit_Soup on `id`, on file name and all the way back to `song.name` on ` the song `object`...to no avail. still `null`. wow, now I'm really curious

Comment: When you changed the id on the html, does `lyricsIntersect` update as well? Does `lyricsIntersect` output `Hot_Bit_Soup` as well?

Comment: yes it did update. mind that when I script `var x = document.getElementById("Hot Bit Soup") and x.play( )`, even with spaces on `id`, I get playback. weird.

Comment: You've remembered to remove the single quotes from the id right? Like `var element = document.getElementById(id);` and not `var element = document.getElementById('id');`

Comment: Awesome. Remember that even though an ID with spaces might work your browser, on some browsers (IE for example) might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   function play_song() {
    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var element = document.getElementById('id');
    element.play();
}
```

I think you're just missing ()'s!

Comment: sorry, I mistyped. my `function` is actually using the correct syntax `element.play()`. I'm stuck here.